# PHP Send Email then Redirect Users

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a very specific honeypot that I am creating. HTACCESS will look at the visitor's IP address and when the site is visited by this IP range, it sends the visitor to this page. When the page loads, I immediately get an email and I want the user to be redirected to another site. However, the user just gets a blank page. Any ideas?

```
<?php 
$to = "xxx@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "xxx VISIT"; 
$message = "xxx VISIT"; 

//mail headers 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n"; 
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n"; 
$headers .= "From: \"example\" <admin@example.com>\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: admin@example.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Receipt-To: admin@example.com\n"; 

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

header("Location: https://www.example.com/");
?>
```

Comment: any error output from the php log?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the logs. Shared hosting. But there is no screen output.

Comment: can you add this code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see any output?

Comment: Where would this need to be added?

Comment: at the beginning, you should see some warning / error on the page.